# ¿Por qué el siguiente código detecta esta matriz como una matriz no singular?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, numpy, matriz

Aquí hay un fragmento de mi código:

```py
import numpy as np
from copy import copy
from random import randint


# Con esta matriz no da error
matriz_aux = [
[None,    6, None,    9],
[   9, None,    3, None],
[None,    5,    4, None]
]

# Con esta matriz da error
matriz_aux = [
[5, 6, None, 5, 5],
[None, None, 3, None, None],
[None, None, 0, None, 1]
]
```

```py
matrix_aux_with_num_decompositions = copy(matriz_aux)

matriz_aux = np.array(matriz_aux)
rows, cols = matriz_aux.shape
seq = np.zeros((rows+cols, rows+cols))
vals = []

# Matriz de configuración que representa el sistema de ecuaciones.
for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
        if matriz_aux[i,j]:
            seq[len(vals), i] = 1
            seq[len(vals), rows + j] = 1
            vals.append(matriz_aux[i,j])

# Establezca valores arbitrarios para que la matriz no sea singular
for extra_eq in range(len(vals), rows+cols):
    seq[extra_eq, extra_eq] = 1
    vals.append(randint(0, 100))

try:
    dcmp = np.linalg.solve(seq, vals)
    for row in range(rows):
        matrix_aux_with_num_decompositions[row].append(dcmp[row])
    matrix_aux_with_num_decompositions.append(list(dcmp[rows:]))
except np.linalg.LinAlgError as e:
    print(f"Error {str(e)}: La matriz es singular. El sistema de ecuaciones lineales no se puede resolver.")

for row in matrix_aux_with_num_decompositions: print(row)
```

Una **salida correcta** podría ser esta matriz de descomposición:

```py
matrix_aux_with_num_decompositions = [
[   5,    6, None,    5,    5,  2],
[None, None,    3, None, None,  1],
[None, None,    0, None,    1, -2],
[   3,    4,    2,    3,    3]
]
```

Para que se resuelva como un sistema de ecuaciones lineales, todos los elementos conocidos deben distribuirse de manera que puedan usarse para construir un sistema de ecuaciones lineales válido, evitando que seq sea una matriz singular, es decir, una matriz que no tiene suficiente información. para resolver el sistema de ecuaciones lineales.

Donde cada uno de los valores numéricos que no eran Ninguno se descompusieron en 2 valores numéricos simples, positivos o negativos, de modo que el valor de su fila y columna sumados los forma.
Y siguiendo la lógica de descomponer aquellos valores numéricos de la matriz que no son Ninguno, en este caso estas serían las operaciones matemáticas:

```
ij_number_to_decompose = i_row_value + j_column_value
5 = 2 + 3
6 = 2 + 4
5 = 2 + 3
5 = 2 + 3
3 = 1 + 2
0 = 2 + (-2)
1 = -2 + 3
```

Tenga en cuenta que el valor de 0 necesariamente debe descomponerse en 2 valores iguales en magnitud pero de signo opuesto;
Creo que este 0 es lo que causa problemas en la lógica de mi código.

Comment: `None` no es un número. ¿Cómo debería interpretarse?

Comment: @Mateo Solo deben descomponerse (en 2 numeros) los valores de los casilleros que no sean None (es decir que sean numericos), los None solo cumplen el rol de organizar los datos en filas y columnas, basicamente estructuran para que los casilleros numericos tengan esas coordenadas pero no deben descomponerse

Comment: Igual hay que tener en cuenta que un casillero None bajo este criterio no debe tratarse igual que un casillero con un valor numérico de 0, el cual si debería descomponerse como la suma de opuestos.